# How many functions exist under given conditions?

Tags: probability

We designate $P(X)$ to be the set of all subsets of $X$. A function $f : P(X) \rightarrow P(X)$ is considered to be "good" if $f(A) \subseteq A$, $\forall A \in P(X)$. Find the probability that by randomly choosing a function $f : P(\{1, 2, 3, 4\}) \rightarrow P(\{1, 2, 3, 4\})$, this function is a "good" one.

We can find the probability by calculating the ration between the favorable cases and possible cases. The possible cases are simply the number of functions that can exist under the given conditions, which is $16^{16}$ or $2^{64}$.

Now, we have to find the favorable cases. I have a bit of a problem here. I found a number, but I'm not sure it's correct. It's $16^5 \cdot 11^6 \cdot 5^4$.

Can someone tell me if I was right, and if I wasn't, please explain how to get the correct answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $4 \choose i$ subsets of size $i$ and each can map to $2^i$ subsets to be good. Therefore, the total number is
$$
\prod_i (2^i)^{4 \choose i} = 16^1\cdot 8^4\cdot 4^6\cdot2^4\cdot 1^1
$$

Comment: Can you, please, explain how you got that result?

Comment: @GeorgeR. Consider for each subset of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ how many subsets it can map to. For example, for the subset $\{1, 2\}$, to be good, it can map to one of $\emptyset$, $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$ and $\{1, 2\}$. Totally $2^2 = 4$ options. More generally, each subset of size $i$ can map to $2^i$ subsets to be good. All we need to do next then is to multiply the # of options of all subsets.

Answer (score 1):

X having 4 elements, P(X) has $2^4$ elements. Then we may build ${P(X)}^{P(X)}$ functions, ${2^4}^{2^4} = 2^{64}$ distinct functions.

Favorable solutions are those where each subset of X is linked to one of its container or itself. We know  $c$ , the cardinal of X ; each subset of cardinal C may have $2^{c-C}$ containers. Then the number of favorable functions is

$\prod_{i=0}^c (2^{c-i})^{\binom{c}{i}} = $

$\prod_{i=0}^4 (2^{4-i})^{\binom{4}{i}} = 2^{32}$

then the probability is $2^{-32}$

( sorry, I was elsewhere )